# JPA 2.1 NamedSubgraph in Hibernate ignoring subclasses

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8.FINAL and have the following model where a Department has many Employees, and an Employee can be a Manager.

The Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "payroll")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Department department;
}
```

The Manager entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manager", schema = "payroll")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Manager extends Employee
{
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "car_allowance")
    private boolean carAllowance;
}
```

The Department entity:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "Graph.Department.FetchManagers",
        includeAllAttributes = false,
        attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "employees", subgraph = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers")
        },
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers",
                        type = Employee.class,
                        attributeNodes = {
                                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name")
                        }
                ),
                @NamedSubgraph(
                        name = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers",
                        type = Manager.class,
                        attributeNodes = {
                                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "carAllowance"),
                        }
                )
        }
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "department", schema = "payroll")
public class Department
{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

As shown in the Department entity, I'm trying to create an @NamedSubgraph that loads all the employees and to also fetch Manager.carAllowance.  However I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [carAllowance] on this ManagedType [com.nemea.hydra.model.test.Employee]
```

From my understanding, the @NamedSubgraph.type should be used to specify the entity subclass attributes to be fetched.  Is it possible that Hibernate is ignoring the type=Manager.class attribute of the @NamedSubgraph annotation or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be the imperfection of Hibernate 4.3.8.FINAL, as e.g. EclipseLink 2.5.1 does not throw the exception when `subgraphs` attribute is used.

Anyway it should work when you specify `subclassSubgraphs` rather than `subclass` in case of `Manager` type, that is:

```java
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Graph.Department.FetchManagers", 
    includeAllAttributes = false,
    attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "employees", subgraph = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers")
    },
    subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers",
            type = Employee.class,
            attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name")
            }
        )
    },
    subclassSubgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(
            name = "FetchManagers.Subgraph.Managers",
            type = Manager.class,
            attributeNodes = {
                @NamedAttributeNode(value = "carAllowance"),
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: I have another issue with nested subgraphs in another question.  I'd appreciate if you could have a look too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645613/jpa-2-1-namedsubgraph-in-hibernate-ignoring-nested-subgraphs